# Why is CALayer allocating all this memory, and how can I track it down?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, calayer, instruments

I'm going through the Allocations instrument, trying to clean up my admittedly terrible memory use.

As per Apple's advice, I take heapshots while repeatedly performing an action, to make sure the memory is freed up.  For the most part it works well, but I'm stumped by this one:

[image: stack trace]

It's a 464KB allocation somewhere in CALayer display, that never gets cleaned up. The worst part is that it's inconsistent - it doesn't happen right away (in this case it happened on the 10th iteration of my repeated action, and the number varies).  The usual heap growth per action is under 20KB (still cleaning that up), but this one really stands out.  I can't find any pattern for when it happens, or why.

How can I track it down?

Answer (score 0):

That is about how much memory is needed to back any full-screen UIView's drawing layer if an app does any drawing into that view.  You can't clean that up as long as that view is allocated and showing.

Comment: Something like that is my best guess... but I'm at a loss to track it down: no view is being displayed that isn't displayed during other iterations, and I don't see any views or view controllers left behind in Allocations.

Comment: Your app might be displaying something different some iterations.